# Seaborn Reg Plots with the same Y Axis scale (Side by Side)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two reg plots in seaborn

```
sb.regplot(x="V", y="Matrix Time", data = df_1, scatter_kws={"color": "b"}, line_kws={"color": "red"})
sb.regplot(x="V", y="List Time", data = df_1, scatter_kws={"color": "g"}, line_kws={"color": "red"})
```

I want to display these plots side by side with the same scale on the Y-axis. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Edit: I tried using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(16,8))
sb.regplot(x="V", y="Matrix Time", data=df_1, ax=ax[0], scatter_kws={"color": "b"}, line_kws={"color": "red"})
sb.regplot(x="V", y="List Time", data=df_1, ax=ax[1], scatter_kws={"color": "g"}, line_kws={"color": "red"})
```

and while it did give me the 2 graphs side by side of the same size. The scale of the Y-axes for each graph were different.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkIUO.png

I was hoping to get both graph side by side such that the values on the Y axis of each graph are on the same horizontal level. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28iko.png

(I created the above image by taking a screenshot of each graph in powerpoint and adjusting the size such that the y axis values are at the same level)

Comment: In `plt.subplots(...)` you can set `sharey=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you need write:

```
sb.regplot(x="V", y="Matrix Time", data = df_1, scatter_kws={"color": "b"}, line_kws={"color": "red"}, ax=ax[0]) 
sb.regplot(x="V", y="List Time", data = df_1, scatter_kws={"color": "g"}, line_kws={"color": "red"}, ax=ax[1])
```

And for your edited Question, you need `plt.subplots(..., sharey=True)`.
I write example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True)
sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, ax=ax[0])
sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips.loc[:10], ax=ax[1])
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @HarshRaoDhanyamraju welcome Dude, thanks for supporting me but here when you edit the question please give comment for users that send the answer for the previous question because when other user see answer don't match to edited question give downvote